# How to retrieve the locale(country) code from URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL, which is like http://example.com/UK/Deal.aspx?id=322

My target is to remove the locale(country) part, to make it like http://example.com/Deal.aspx?id=322

Since the URL may have other similar formats like: https://ssl.example.com/JP/Deal.aspx?id=735, using **"substring"** function is not a good idea.

What I can think about is to use the following method for separating them, and map them back later.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query
```

And, suppose  **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath** will be:

```
/UK/Deal.aspx?id=322
```

I am not sure how to deal with this since my boss asked me not to use "regular expression"(he thinks it will impact performance...)

**Except** "*Regular Expression*", is there any other way to remove **UK** from it?

p.s.: the **UK** part may be **JP**, **DE**, or other country code.

By the way, for USA, there is no country code, and the url will be http://example.com/Deal.aspx?id=322

Please also take this situation into consideration.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to remove and map them back? Is it because of the locale is automatically getting appended to you Urls when accessing the website from different region or country? if yes, then there could be another solution.

Comment: Hi @vendettamit, actually my website is adding "multi-regions" in these days, and my legacy URL related methods will not work right if there is extra "Country code". I try to remove "country code" from URL(with country code) before going to these legacy methods, and map it back after processing.

Comment: Gotach!! You can use a little regex to match if Url segment have the 2 letter ISO code as first ocurrance after root. @user3174976 See my updated answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with regex optimization tac-tics. Should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you'll have `TwoLetterCountryISOName` in the Url. yYou can use `UriBuilder` class to remove the path from `Uri` without using the `Regex`.

E.g.

```
    var originalUri = new Uri("http://example.com/UK/Deal.aspx?id=322");
    if (IsLocaleEnabled(sourceUri))
       {
         var builder = new UriBuilder(sourceUri);
         builder.Path 
          = builder.Path.Replace(sourceUri.Segments[1] /* remove UK/ */, string.Empty);
          // Construct the Uri with new path
          Uri newUri = builder.Uri;;
       }
```

> Update:

```
// Cache the instance for performance benefits.
static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[aA-zZ]{2}\/$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

/// <summary>
/// Regex to check if Url segments have the 2 letter 
/// ISO code as first ocurrance after root
/// </summary>
private bool IsLocaleEnabled(Uri sourceUri)
{
  // Update: Compiled regex are way much faster than using non-compiled regex.
  return regex.IsMatch(sourceUri.Segments[1]);
}
```

For **performance** benefits you must cache it *(means keep it in static readonly field)*. There's no need to parse a pre-defined regex on every request. This way you'll get all the performance benefits you can get.

Result - `http://example.com/Deal.aspx?id=322`

Comment: Hi @vendettamit, if my URL is http://example.com/Deal.aspx?id=322 for USA(without country code), is there any way to ignore your replace method in this sitaution? Thank you.

Comment: hmm!! you would need an extra check to verfiy if the url have country code specified.

Comment: When you initialize your builder, you need to also provide the initial path.  Otherwise, it defaults to a loopback URI, and then your replace does nothing.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus Correct! Thanks for pointing out. Updated the code.

Comment: And this does not work if the URL given is of the form "/UK/Deal.aspx?id=322" which is one of the possibilities presented by the OP.

Comment: That's path not Url. I think he's dealing with a different issue. It might be tha case that his application is auto selecting the culture for Localization which is why he wants to replace it and map the path to default one.

Comment: @vendettamit - you are right, I read his post wrong and thought he was saying the URI could come in without scheme and host.

Comment: @user3174976 Updated the answer to avoid performance glitches of using `Regex`. It will perform faster then using `Strings` `Contains` method.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether the country code always has the same position. If it's not, then some more details on the possible formats are required.. Maybe you could check, if the first segment has two chars or something, to be sure it really is a country code (not sure if this is reliable though). Or you start with the filename, if it's always in the format `/[optionalCountryCode]/deal.aspx?...`

How about these two approaches (on string level):

```
public string RemoveCountryCode()
{
  Uri originalUri = new Uri("http://example.com/UK/Deal.aspx?id=322");
  string hostAndPort = originalUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

  // v1: if country code is always there, always has same position and always
  // has format 'XX' this is definitely the easiest and fastest
  string trimmedPathAndQuery = originalUri.PathAndQuery.Substring("/XX/".Length);

  // v2: if country code is always there, always has same position but might
  // not have a fixed format (e.g. XXX)
  trimmedPathAndQuery = string.Join("/", originalUri.PathAndQuery.Split('/').Skip(2));

  // in both cases you need to join it with the authority again
  return string.Format("{0}/{1}", hostAndPort, trimmedPathAndQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the AbsolutePath will always have the format `/XX/...pagename.aspx?id=###` where `XX` is the two letter country code, then you can just strip off the first 3 characters.

Example that removes the first 3 characters:

```
var targetURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(3);
```

If the country code could be different lengths, then you could find the index of the second `/` character and start the substring from there.

```
var sourceURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
var firstOccurance = sourceURL.IndexOf('/')
var secondOccurance = sourceURL.IndexOf('/', firstOccurance);

var targetURL = sourceURL.Substring(secondOccurance);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to treat as string, split it by the "/" separator, remove the fourth element, and then join them back with the "/" separator again:

```
    string myURL = "https://ssl.example.com/JP/Deal.aspx?id=735";
    List<string> myURLsplit = myURL.Split('/').ToList().RemoveAt(3);
    myURL = string.Join("/", myURLsplit);

RESULT: https://ssl.example.com/Deal.aspx?id=735
```